# How to restrict some users and public from accessing uploaded files using php yii framework

Tags: php, file-upload, yii, privileges, yii-extensions

I have created a php application using Yii. It has user, public and admin modules.

On a file upload, user should be able to set access privileges (e.g. public, private, a specific group, etc).

I want to restrict people from accessing files via URL.

- How can I solve this problem?
- Is Yii providing any built mechanism for this?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent anyone from accessing files in the uploads folder, place a `.htaccess` file inside:

```
deny from all
```

Then, to allow certain users from accessing the file, create a controller action:

```
private function actionDownload($fileId) {
    $file = File::model()->findByPk(fileId);
    $filePath = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../uploads/'.$file->filename;

    // Check user permissions
    if($file->permissions != 'public' && $file->userId != Yii::app()->user->id)
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'This file does not belong to you.');

    // Download file to user
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $filePath);
    finfo_close($finfo);
    $size = filesize($filePath);

    header("Content-Type: ".$mime);
    header("Content-Length: ".$size);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$fileName."\"");
    readfile($filePath);

    exit;
}
```

Example URLs, depending on your preferred set-up:

```
http://example.com/download/1
http://example.com/site/download/1
http://example.com/site/download?fileId=1
```